# How to read smarty config variable from PHP behind?

Tags: php, smarty

What function can I use in PHP for class Smarty which reads a variable's value from the Smarty's config file?

Here's my code:

```
<?

session_start();

require('libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->config_load("settings.conf");

include('settings.php');
include('meta.php');

$smarty->debugging = false;
$smarty->caching =false;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;



include("categories.php");
include("manufacturers.php");
include("logos.php");

print_r($smarty->getConfigVariable("showCategories"));

close_database_session($dbconn);

//$smarty->display('index.tpl');



?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [`get_config_vars()`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.get.config.vars.php) (you have to load the configuration beforehand with [`config_load()`](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.config.load.php)).

Example from the documentation:

```
// get loaded config template var #foo#
$myVar = $smarty->get_config_vars('foo');

// get all loaded config template vars
$all_config_vars = $smarty->get_config_vars();
```

**Update (Smarty 3.0 RC1):**

For Smarty 3.0 RC1 it is

```
$smarty->configLoad($config_file, $sections = null)
// and
$smarty->getConfigVariable($variable)
```

Note there is no official documentation yet but the methods available are listed in the included README file.

Comment: here's what I'm getting from the PHP now: 

Notice: function call 'config_load' is unknown or deprecated. in C:\xampp\htdocs\rondcom\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_wrapper.php on line 57

I'm using smarty 3.

Comment: @Ervin: Updated my answer, the methods are listed in the README file.

Comment: It's working, but the error message is being given. But if I put @ in front then everything's fine. 

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I did it using this code:

```
$templ->fetch('template_that_loads_config.tpl');
print_r($templ->_config[0]['vars']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`smarty->configLoad(...)` produces a notice like

> "Notice: function call 'config_load' is unknown or deprecated."

A workaround is putting an @ in front of the call like 
`@smarty->configLoad($cfgFile)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to get your smarty assigned config variables:

`print_r` of your `$smarty` object and note down your config variables.

Get those variables of say `settings.conf`:

```
 $category_title1 = $smarty->_config[0]['vars']['driving_license_category'];
```

You can then use as you like it in PHP.